# Xamarin Android image url array into gridview

Tags: c#, android, mysql, visual-studio, xamarin

I just want to change my resource.drawable.image into URL, but I don't know how I can do that. I try using bitmap method but I don't know how I can make it array using this method. The purpose of this is I want to get the data from the database and store it into my `List<>` or array so the output will be like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0eBY.png). It's working fine in resource.drawable.image but I want to change into into url value.

By the way, I already stored the column ID from the database. I also try to store the image_link column from the database into my while loop and call it into my List<> but I get error. See my code at below --> Fragment1.cs 
All of these codes are working.

fragment_layout.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/grid_view_image_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:columnWidth="110dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

gridview_layout.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewGrid"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewGrid"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

CustomGridViewAdapter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace testing_code
{
    public class CustomGridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private string[] gridViewString;
        private int[] gridViewImage;
        public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, string[] gridViewstr, int[] gridViewImage)
        {
            this.context = context;
            gridViewString = gridViewstr;
            this.gridViewImage = gridViewImage;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return gridViewString.Length;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                view = new View(context);
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gridview_layout, null);
                TextView txtview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewGrid);
                ImageView imgview = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewGrid);

                txtview.Text = gridViewString[position];
                imgview.SetImageResource(gridViewImage[position]);
            }
            else
            {
                view = (View)convertView;
            }
            return view;
        }

        //private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        //{
        //    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        //    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        //    {
        //        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        //        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        //        {
        //            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        //        }
        //    }

        //    return imageBitmap;
        //}
    }
}
```

---

Fragment1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace testing_code
{
    public class Fragment1 : SupportFragment
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

        string query = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=dbsample;user id=root;password=123";

        GridView gridview;

        //string[] gridviewstring = {
        //        "location", "sound", "note"
        //};

        //int[] imgview =
        //{
        //    Resource.Drawable.ic_dashboard, Resource.Drawable.ic_headset, Resource.Drawable.ic_dashboard
        //};

        List<string> gridviewstring = new List<string>();
        List<int> imgview = new List<int>();


        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


            conn.ConnectionString = query;

            // 
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from wp_kdskli23jkposts where ID in (1,2,4)", conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read, get and loop the data value from the database
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string asd = reader["ID"].ToString();

                    gridviewstring.Add(asd);
                }
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder except = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
                except.SetTitle("Please report this to our website(error server timeout)");
                except.SetMessage(ex.ToString());
                except.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    except.Dispose();
                });
                except.Show();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            //gridviewstring.Add("location");
            //gridviewstring.Add("music");
            //gridviewstring.Add("book");



            imgview.Add(Resource.Drawable.ic_dashboard);
            imgview.Add(Resource.Drawable.ic_headset);
            imgview.Add(Resource.Drawable.ic_dashboard);

            string[] GridViewStringArray = gridviewstring.ToArray();
            int[] GridImgViewArray = imgview.ToArray();

            CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(Activity, GridViewStringArray, GridImgViewArray);
            gridview = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.grid_view_image_text);
            gridview.Adapter = adapter;
            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it an online image or a local image in your drawable folder and you need the uri or file path?

Comment: the resource.drawable.image i made is in local file. Yes it is in drawable folder. Yes exactly! I want to change the resource.drawable.image into url so I can get the value of image_link column from the database and call it in my List<> array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your adapter code to use a list of strings

```
  namespace testing_code
{
    public class CustomGridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private List<string> gridViewString;
        private List<string> gridViewImage;
        public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> gridViewstr, List<string> gridViewImage)
        {
            this.context = context;
            gridViewString = gridViewstr;
            this.gridViewImage = gridViewImage;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return gridViewString.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                view = new View(context);
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gridview_layout, null);
                TextView txtview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewGrid);
                ImageView imgview = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewGrid);

                txtview.Text = gridViewString[position];
                imgview.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(gridViewImage[position]));
            }
            else
            {
                view = (View)convertView;
            }
            return view;
        }

        private Android.Graphics.Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
               }


            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your fragment to use list of URL strings

```
public class Fragment1 : SupportFragment
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

    string query = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=dbsample;user id=root;password=123";

    GridView gridview;



    List<string> gridviewstring = new List<string>();
    List<string> imgview = new List<string>();


    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


        conn.ConnectionString = query;

        // 
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from wp_kdskli23jkposts where ID in (1,2,4)", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read, get and loop the data value from the database
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string asd = reader["ID"].ToString();

                gridviewstring.Add(asd);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder except = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            except.SetTitle("Please report this to our website(error server timeout)");
            except.SetMessage(ex.ToString());
            except.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                except.Dispose();
            });
            except.Show();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }




        imgview.Add(" https://www.bellanaija.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Remy-Martins-Pacesetters-VIP-Party-BellaNaija-November2013023-600x398.jpg");
        imgview.Add("http://www.allevents.ng/media/2018/at-the-club-with-remy-martins.png?width=375&mode=crop");

        imgview.Add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iLZz9Becq98/maxresdefault.jpg");


        CustomGridViewAdapter adapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(Activity, gridviewstring, imgview);
        gridview = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.grid_view_image_text);
        gridview.Adapter = adapter;
        return view;
    }

}
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: WTF! DUDE YOU ARE A GOD. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR SAVING MY LIFE! YOU ARE AWESOME! THIS METHOD IS REALLY WORKING. I MEAN SMOOTH WORKING. THANK YOU AGAIN DUDE AND SORRY FOR MY LATE REPLY.

Comment: Tolupe! May i ask? Can you help me again :( for how to turn this into asynchronous like async task...  My android getting freeze when i load the images 2 or more. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check my answer under your new question